# read contents of all xml tags that start with a certain string

Tags: regex, xml, perl, xml-parsing

I have an xml structure where I'm looking to write a perl script that reads the content of all tags that start with a certain string.

Example:

```
<tag-0>
    <tag-1>This is<tag-2>some example</tag2>text</tag-1>
    <tag-3>This is some <ice-8> more </ice-8>text</tag-3>
    <tag-4>This 
        <tag-5>is 
            <tag-6>even more</tag-6>
        </tag-5> 
        <tag-7> text</tag-7>
    </tag-4>
</tag-0>
```

The purpose of the script is to find all nodes that start with `<tag-[num]>` that contain a nested `<tag-[num]>`. I'm not familiar with perl, so how would I go about reading contents of a "dynamic" tag, and checking for more dynamic nesting tags?

In the above example, I would want to get tag-0, tag-1, tag-4, and tag-5, which I would then be able to further manipulate their contents.

Comment: Use a real XML parser and then test the element names.   Don't try to parse XML with regex.

Answer (score 2):

[`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod) is my most used XML module - there are plenty others, but this one does just about everything I need, at the expense of sometimes being a little more verbose than other modules. The following prints the four desired nodes:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::LibXML;

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => <<'EOT');
<tag-0>
    <tag-1>This is<tag-2>some example</tag-2>text</tag-1>
    <tag-3>This is some <ice-8> more </ice-8>text</tag-3>
    <tag-4>This 
        <tag-5>is 
            <tag-6>even more</tag-6>
        </tag-5> 
        <tag-7> text</tag-7>
    </tag-4>
</tag-0>
EOT

my $expr = "*[substring(name(), 1, 4) = 'tag-']";
for my $node ( $dom->findnodes("//$expr") ) {
    my @children = $node->findnodes("./$expr");
    if (@children) {
        print $node->nodeName,"\n";
    }
}
```

Note that your problem description is a little unclear: does *"contain a nested `<tag-[num]>`"* mean that only direct descendants are to be considered, or should `<tag-0>A<x>B<tag-1>C</tag-1>D</x>E</tag-0>` also return `tag-0`?

If so, then you can change the second `findnodes` expression to `".//$expr"`.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a direct descendant, so tag-0 would still be returned in that case!

Answer (score 1):

Using [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mojo::DOM;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new->xml(1)->parse($xml);

my @tags_with_subtags = $dom->find('*')->grep(sub {
  $_->tag =~ m/\Atag-[0-9]+\z/ and $_->find('*')->grep(sub {
    $_->tag =~ m/\Atag-[0-9]+\z/
  })->size
})->each;
```

Each of the results is a Mojo::DOM object you can further search or manipulate. CSS unfortunately is not (as far as I know) well suited for finding dynamic tag names, so you have to do this bit yourself; it would be very easy if it was instead dynamic attributes.